# Laravel 4 - Validator - File Size

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

Just a query about Laravels' validator. Users' of my site are going to be uploading files at times that are possibly going to be around the 100MB Mark.

I've looked at : http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation

My controller code is as follows :

```
$rules = array(
 'file' => 'max:102400'
);
```

Is 102400 the equivalent of 100MB, I don't feel the docs are clear enough on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described in the docs:

> max:value
>
> The field under validation must be less than or equal to a maximum
>   value. **Strings, numerics, and files are evaluated in the same fashion
>   as the size rule**

So we go to the Size rule:

> size:value
>
> The field under validation must have a size matching the given value.
>   For string data, value corresponds to the number of characters. For
>   numeric data, value corresponds to a given integer value. **For files,
>   size corresponds to the file size in kilobytes**.

So the 102400 is Kilobytes.

Yes that is 100 MB.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the best way to find out would be to check the source at [Github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L934).

Specifically:

`return $value->getSize() / 1024;`

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte), a kilobyte "refers to either 1000 bytes or 1024 bytes, depending on usage and context", therefore the documentation seems to be a bit ambiguous.

Comment: +1 just for a solution to problems that are actually not clear in the docs. Even though I totally disagree with being the 'best solution'.

Comment: @Loko It's not the best solution as in "always read the code before the docs", but it sure helps a lot to dig into the codebase if the documentation is not clear on the subject.

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant. If the documentation is not clear, this is a great solution.